# Understanding 勝手

Tags: grammar, words, nuances

Maruko has been told that she can't have the food she wants, and replies:

> 「いいじゃん別にっ。 いつか食べられる日を夢見るくらい、まる子の**勝手**でしょ。」
>   ????. To the extent of dreaming of a day, some day, when I can eat (it), Maruko's ??? is.

I can't find a dictionary definition for 勝手 that makes sense here. The best fit seems to be "circumstances" i.e.

"My (Maruko's) circumstances are such that I dream of a day when I can eat it.",

If my translation is correct then it sounds very dramatic/formal in English. What nuance is this sentence structure adding over the more simple:

> いつか食べられる日を夢見る

I'd also be grateful if you could tell me what いいじゃん別に means.

Comment: いいじゃん別に　can mean "no big deal", "who cares", "whatever" and several other similar things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would translate “いいじゃん別に。いつか食べられる日を夢見るくらい、まる子の勝手でしょ” to “It’s none of your business. Leave it to me (Maruko) how I dream of the day's coming when I can eat it to the full.”

勝手 means freedom of doing something. Here it means “It’s all up to me." We often tell an uncontrollable person “勝手にしろ – Do whatever you want! I don’t care a bit.”

Comment: If the one who doesn't want to be cared what he/she does says 私の勝手だ, the best translation I can think of is "You can't tell me what to do."

Answer (score 2):

[This dictionary entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/42832/meaning/m0u/%E5%8B%9D%E6%89%8B/) fits perfectly:

> ［名・形動］
>
> １ 他人のことはかまわないで、自分だけに都合がよいように振る舞うこと。また、そのさま。「そんな―は許さない」「―なことを言うな」「―に使っては困る」「―にしろ」

Essentially, doing whatever one wants; not caring about what other people think.

---

Here's my take on the translation:

> いいじゃん別にっ。 いつか食べられる日を夢見るくらい、まる子の勝手でしょ。
>
> What do you care? I can dream about eating it however much I want.

Although, my phrasing, especially "what do you care", can sound a bit confrontational. You might want to phrase it more like: "what's the big deal" or "it's fine though, isn't it?" Similarly, adding "can't I?" to the end of the second sentence might make it less definitive and softer.