# How is 勝手 being used here?

Tags: words

In death note, at one point in the conversation there is this line:

> 誰をキラだと疑おうと勝手だが、あの面は自分だけ助かろうという気持ちの現れじゃないか。

The speaker is trying to tell the other guy that he doesn't care who he suspects, but he wants him to take the mask off, since it's just to protect himself only anyways.

What I thought is that perhaps my subtitles are wrong and it's supposed to be 買って being used as "accept", but I checked 2 subtitles and both used 勝手. How does 勝手 mean "I don't care"?

Comment: Literally I guess it's a little closer to 'You're free to', 'it's your choice'

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32577/45489

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding 勝手](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32577/5010) Very literally, it's "(that's your) discretion".

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I understand now.